# Time-stamping JSON fields when created or updated

Tags: java, android, json, timestamp, field

I would like to create JSON files that have the timestamp for each operation on their fields. This kind of JSON files are to be used only by my Android app, so they have not to be "standard".

When one of these JSON files is updated, its old version is read first, then a comparison is performed and only modified fields get a new timestamp. Then the new version is written.

Timestamps could be just fields with similar keys, but with a suffix. For example, if the key is **field1** the corresponding timestamp field could be **field1_timestamp**. This method allows retrocompatibility with files without timestamps.

(timestamps can be numbers or strings)

Example:

```
{
  "key1":value1,
  "key1_timestamp":"1223911298",
  "key2":"value2",
  "key2_timestamp":"1223911298",
  "arrayKey":[
    {
      "keyA":valueA,
      "keyB":"valueB",
      "keyA_timestamp":"1223911298",
      "keyB_timestamp":"1223911298",
      "keyC":[
        0,
        1,
        2
      ],
      "keyC_timestamp":"1223911298"
    },
    {
      "keyA":anotherValueA,
      "keyB":"anotherValueB",
      "keyA_timestamp":"1223911298",
      "keyB_timestamp":"1223911298",
      "keyC":[
        4,
        5,
        6
      ],
      "keyC_timestamp":"1223911298"
    }
  ],
  "arrayKey_timestamp":"1223911298"
}
```

I would know if it is a good or bad practice.
Are there other ways?
Further suggestions on all aspects of this idea are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need this information, your approach looks right to me. I think I have seen something similar before.

I am wondering what your business case is and whether you really need all those timestamps. Since I don’t know your business case, I cannot guide you here. If it were me, I would ask myself twice for each field “What do I need a timestamp for this field for?”

I recommend strings in UTC in ISO 8601 format for the timestamps, for example `2008-10-13T15:21:38Z` (this example corresponds to your example value assuming that that was a Unix timestamp). When debugging surprising timestamps, you will love the readability.

**Link:** [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)